# Android eclipse add pressed state to ImageView

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview

Is there a way to add a pressed state to an ImageView?  I have an image that i place a click listener on, and when I press it I want to change to imageview src for a second to mimic the pressed state of buttons or listview items.

Can I add a selector xml to the src attribute?

Figured it out.  You CAN add a selector xml to your src attribute of an ImageView.
In my case, i created "addbuttonbg.xml" in my drawables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/quickaddbutton" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/quickaddbutton_click" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/quickaddbutton" />
</selector>
```

Then set your imageview src to @drawable/addbuttonbg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can add a selector to get the press effect

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/postbutton_press" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/postbutton_press" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/postbutton_normal"/>

</selector>
```

To the ImageView's android:src="@drawable/post_btn_click" attribute or android:background="@drawable/post_btn_click" to a button attribute

post_btn_click -> selector drawable's file name